# My website loading heavy images. I need to re-size it from server how it possible?

Tags: image, wordpress, load

My website loading heavy images. I need to re-size it from server how it possible?. 
here is the url of the website : www.thefirstdrive.com

Comment: Resize it from the server?
Why can't you just upload smaller versions of the image?

Comment: have you tried `wp super cache plugin` to make cachable image instead of resizing images??

Comment: Why from the server? Is that a service you offer to the visitors? Beside, what the Wordpress tag is making here? You need to be more explicit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Resize the images and upload them again.

or

1. use imagemagick and resize the images via ssh.

Comment: It has lot of images I don't know its possible to do manually. BTW its a wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

this could be what you are looking for

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/